# Template page--node--<id>.tpl.php not working

Tags: 7, theming

I've created a page node for an about page. I've checked the node id of the node which is 11.
I've created a file named page--node--11.tpl.php in my theme directory containing some test html but it's not overriding the standard page.tpl.php file.
I've also tried using the following file names:
page-node-11.tpl.php
page-node--11.tpl.php

I've cleared the cache but still no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there anything in template.php that could be causing the issue? Specifically check THEME_preprocess_page or THEME_preprocess_node if they exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) it should be `page--node--11.tpl.php` (note the double dashes):

> page--[front|internal/path].tpl.php
>       base template: page.tpl.php
>   The suggestions are numerous. The one that takes precedence is for the front page. The rest are based on the internal path of the current page. Do not confuse the internal path to path aliases which are not accounted for. Keep in mind that the commonly-used Pathauto module uses path aliases.
>
> The front page can be set at "Administration > Configuration > System > Site information." In Drupal 6, at "Administrator > Site configuration > Site information." Anything set there will trigger the suggestion of "page--front.tpl.php" for it.
>
> The list of suggested template files is in order of specificity based on internal paths. One suggestion is made for every element of the current path, though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent suggestions. For example, "http://www.example.com/node/1/edit" would result in the following suggestions:
>
> - page--node--edit.tpl.php
> - page--node--1.tpl.php
> - page--node.tpl.php
> - page.tpl.php
>
> Also see page.tpl.php in the Drupal API documentation for more information.

Comment: I've tried that as well, cleared out the cache and still the same thing - page.tpl.php is being called.

Comment: The URL is: <mysite.com>/?q=node/11 and my file is named node--11.tpl.php

Comment: @beth, this would be correct if the result desired is that the actual content of `node/11` be formatted differently in the content region of the standard page.  if however, a custom page layout itself for displaying `node/11` is desired, then `page--node--11.tpl.php` is correct.  Assuming D7.

Comment: Thanks jimajamma, it's the latter I'm after. However, neither files are overriding the defaults.

Comment: Right you are @Jimajamma. Edited.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I'm clear on the theory now, any ideas why why override is not being picked up?

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: If you have a `page.tpl.php` file, check if it is being picked up and if so that your `page--node--11.tpl.php` is in the same directory.  make sure the name is precisely correct, eg, sometimes on MS based machines, the extension isn't printed and people have created `page.tpl.php.php` to see it (albeit incorrectly).  clear caches (duh lol).  install devel and check what the theme engine is doing on each page.

Comment: page.tpl.php is definitely being picked up. I've just added some text to the top of it and it's being displayed. page--node--11.tpl.php is in the same folder and has the same permissions (it's a linux machine). Caches cleared (drush cc all). I navigate to my about page (node 11) by clicking the menu item about and I'm taken to http://<mysite.com>/?q=node/11# and it's still using the page.tpl.php page. I'm using Drupal 7.22. Devel is now installed, just looking through it.

Comment: I've got it working, I disabled the modules theme developer and libraries and it started using my page--node--11.tpl.php! I expect it was the Theme Developer module? Many many thanks for your help and patience everyone!